# does 1 row from excel worksheets exist in another worksheet. If so copy, copy value from cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document tracking vulnerabilities.  Each scan we add another worksheet(tab).  If the exact vulnerability exists from the previous scan (matching several columns), I would like to copy the "RemPlan" and "RemDate" cells to the new tab if there is something occupying those cells to avoid the manual entry

the columns are the following:

*sheet 1 (Old sheet)*

```
**RemPlan   RemDate   Risk    Host      Port    Description**   
do stuff  1/1/1111   Med     xxx.xx.x.9 22     ssh stuff
                     Med     xxx.xx.x.9 335     ssh stuff
                     Med     xxx.xx.x.9 45     ssh stuff
do stuff  1/1/2211   Med     xxx.xx.x.1 10     ssh stuff
do stuff  1/1/1111   Med     xxx.xx.x.4 650     ssh stuff
                     Med     xxx.xx.x.1 11     ssh stuff
do stuff  1/1/1111   Med     xxx.xx.x.6 22     ssh other stuff
```

sheet 2 *(New sheet)*

```
**RemPlan   RemDate   Risk    Host        Port  Description**   
                       Med     xxx.xx.x.x   22     ssh stuff
```

I have looked at match, index, and vlookup but can not figure it out.  any help is appreciated

Comment: To give an exact answer, need more information. Do you have something like column B is rem plan, b2= do stuff. column C is remDat C2=1/1/1111 so the last column with info is E, or does it continue further to the right

Comment: Also, can you add helper columns or convert data into tables? Do you have sharing restrictions such as can not change format, use macro's etc.

Comment: Sheet two. What is the reason for this sheet? You have it all on Sheet 1. Please clarify what Sheet2 is used for and how you tried to apply match/vlookup/... FYI: vlookup works when the data is in order only -- thus using a ranking unique qualifier (e.g. ID) AND in numeric-order on your rows. Sheet two: Given "what" to find "...what data..." on Sheet1?

Comment: I figured it out.  I concatenated the cells from each worksheet that I wanted to match on.  then I used the following to return the exception status from the previous worksheet if there was a match   =IF(ISBLANK(INDEX('PCI DSS 08122016'!D:D,MATCH(Q2,'PCI DSS 08122016'!Q:Q,0))),"",INDEX('PCI DSS 08122016'!D:D,MATCH(Q2,'PCI DSS 08122016'!Q:Q,0)))

Answer (score 0):

concatenate the fields you want to match on in a new column for both tabs (P) using
=CONCATENATE(F2, ":", G2, ":", H2, ":", I2, ":", J2, ":", K2)

then

in the cell you want to copy from the previous tab, use this formula(this helps if there is no value then it returns blank instead of zero

=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX('PCI DSS 08122016'!D:D,MATCH(Q2,'PCI DSS 08122016'!Q:Q,0))),"",INDEX('PCI DSS 08122016'!D:D,MATCH(Q2,'PCI DSS 08122016'!Q:Q,0)))